# Looking for a specific book about memories stored in a crystal through the use of a machine

Tags: story-identification

First, I am pretty sure it isn't *Crystal Phoenix* by Michael Berlyn, but the cover is similar to that with a naked woman standing in flames of some kind.

I read the book around 1983-1984 in paperback form.

The memory storage was a machine in everyone's homes that you used to scan and save your memories so that in the event of death your memories would be installed in a new body. Pretty standard of the science fiction world back then.

The main character was a man who for some reason is forced to watch his wife be raped and brutally killed by another man. After this he goes and extracts revenge of those responsible and kills them. The killer of his wife he chooses to sabotage the machine, so when the guy realizes he's going to be on the list he decides to update his memories in storage. But the machine fries him and the crystal storage, killing him permanently. Then the main character goes home to be with his wife who has a new body and has no memory of course of the events surrounding her death.

Thanks you in advance, hopefully I've provided enough info that someone will know this book.

Comment: I do believe this has been asked on this site before; I'll see what I can find

Comment: Thank you, I did find one similar question, but that one had been resolved with the book and author, my research on that one was that it was different, Crystal Phoenix plot was different completely, but if there is another similar question then Thank you in advance for the effort, I've been looking for this rehash read for years

Answer (score 2):

Despite your doubt, this is [Crystal Phoenix](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3277695-crystal-phoenix) by Michael Berlyn, previously identified in [Book: Dystopian Future; Memory Saved on Crystals; Paid Torture for Fun](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135766/book-dystopian-future-memory-saved-on-crystals-paid-torture-for-fun). I found a copy on Archive.org and it does match your description.

The husband and wide are *Dennis* and *Kira Lange*. The murder of Kira is arranged by a business associate of Dennis's called *Freddie Frank* and carried out by a psychopath called *Oleo Johnson*. The scene is on pages [116 and 117](https://archive.org/details/crystalphoenix00berl/page/116/mode/2up) of the book.

The sabotage of the crystal is described on pages [189 to 191](https://archive.org/details/crystalphoenix00berl/page/188/mode/2up). Dennis threatens Oleo with a gun but then leaves. Oleo is shaken and decides to make a backup with his crystal:

> Maybe he was just jumpy. Yeah. Lange had been bluffing, trying to get him to lose control so he would have an excuse for pulling the trigger. And maybe not.
>
> Check the crystal, he thought, then answer the blasted phone. If Lange destroyed it, then get out of the house, get to a Center, get the crystal replaced, update it, and keep it at the Center.
>
> Yeah. The crystal first.
>
> He walked into his bedroom, ignoring the invisible daggers, the no-existent bombs, the heatless flames, and glanced at the crystal.
>
> It hadn't been harmed. It sat there sparkling like a deep, dark ruby, like crystalline blood. He sat down in its attached chair mechanism, swung the clear helmet down over the top of his head to update the crystal - just in case Lange did somehow get to him before he got another chance to update it.
>
> He pressed the button.
>
> The criss-crossing lasers sizzled through the top layer of hair, then flesh, then bone, then finally, brain tissue. The beams met at billions of intersections, mapping every newly-charred synapse, every newly destroyed chemical interaction, burning their ways through Oleo's skull, cooking it from the inside and outside. The beams did the same thing to the crystal that they had done to the head that had once belonged to Albert "Oleo" Johnson.

Comment: Didn't know Berlyn, the Infocom Implementer, wrote a novel! adding another book to the TBR file...