# Mind Transfer story where people are paid to be murdered and restored without remembering

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a story where you can sign up to be paid to be murdered in creative ways. The person killing you pays for the expensive process to have you restored into a new clone plus a considerable cash sum. You are restored to a point just before your murder so you don't recall your gruesome death. I think I read it in the 1980s or 90s but can't recall title or author. I think the recording of your personality involved storage in a crystal of some sort and in a particularly sadistic twist one person was set to experience continuous updates as they were being tortured so they would remember the experience when they were restored.

Comment: Is it possibly the same one as this one? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135766/book-dystopian-future-memory-saved-on-crystals-paid-torture-for-fun?rq=1

Comment: Yes that looks like the same one. Many thanks! I'll chase down a copy to confirm but I'm pretty sure you found it.