# Story where memories are stored in crystals inside a wig

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I am looking for a teen science fiction title published in the late 1970s or early 1980s. I believe that there was a society that has found a way to prolong life for hundreds of years. Individuals store their memories in crystals that reside in a wig. When a character wants to live in the moment, they can remove their wig and be free of other memories. Sorry-no title or author.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF! You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in any more details you may remember? Also don't forget to register your account and take the [tour]!

Comment: Does [this question/answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135766/book-dystopian-future-memory-saved-on-crystals-paid-torture-for-fun?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) look familiar?

Comment: There is no mention of wigs in Crystal Phoenix by Michael Berlyn

Answer (score 3):

This might be Sharon Webb's "[*Ram Song*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6513060-ram-song)", the 3rd in her "*Earth Child*" trilogy; it was initially published in 1985. The only thing I can remember about the book are the crystal wigs.

> On the planet Aulos, a strange beam that disorients people is interrupting a yearly festival; the immortal Kurt Kraus and the starship Ram are called to meet the emergency. Sequel to Earthchild and Earth song.